# ROS Melodic with Rpi Cam

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I am trying to learn Autonomous Cars… I am totally new to these things I am trying to do my self driving rc car(1/10 scale). Like Donkeycar.
But i want to realize it with ROS.
I got rpi camera V2. I searched internet and just find that i can use rpi camera with ros kinetic. Are there any way to rpi camera with Jetson Nano on ROS. Cause as i can learned i can only install ros melodic to jetson nano.

Now i am using:

Jetson Nano
JetPack 4.4
ROS Melodic

My questions are:

1. Can i use ros kinetic with jetson nano
2. Can i use rpi cam with ros melodic
3. There is a node for rpi camera like i said (in ros Kinetic) can i use this node in ros melodic

For me it’s urgent. I would be grateful for any help.
Can you help me.
Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/369524/ros-melodic-with-rpi-cam/) by [Morgenstern](https://answers.ros.org/users/55396/morgenstern/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2021-01-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For answer who may search for it:

1. You can only use ROS melodic with
   Jetson Nano. Maybe you can use another destribution but with
   docker.(idk how exactly)
2. If you are searching rpi
   cam V2 ready to use package you can
   check -> [dusty-nv's github
   page](https://github.com/dusty-nv/jetbot_ros)
3. You can't cause some packages may
   not compatible with every version.

---

Originally posted by [Morgenstern](https://answers.ros.org/users/55396/morgenstern/) with karma: 25 on 2021-01-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0